# Openssl library equivalent of java KeyPairGenerator

Tags: java, c++, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to send a RSA public key to a Java client from a c++ server. Since the client is running Java I believe the key needs to be formatted in X509. I need to get the key as an encoded char array but can't find the right way.

I need to find the c++ openssl library equivalent of the following:

```java
public byte[] getEncodedPubKey() {
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator keypairgenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keypairgenerator.initialize(1024);
        return keypairgenerator.generateKeyPair().getPublic().getEncoded();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        //Insert error handling
    }
}
```

This my best attempt in c++ at the solution so far:

```cpp
EVP_PKEY *evpKey = EVP_PKEY_new();
RSA *rsa = RSA_generate_key(1024, RSA_F4, nullptr, nullptr);
EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(evpKey, rsa);

X509 *x = X509_new();
X509_set_pubkey(x, evpKey);

auto *data = (unsigned char*)malloc(165);
X509_PUBKEY *pubkey = X509_get_X509_PUBKEY(x);
int size = i2d_X509_PUBKEY(pubkey, &data);

std::vector<unsigned char> encodedKey(data, data+size);
```

To provide more information, this is what java client does once receiving the encoded public key:

```java
public PublicKey decodePubKey(byte[] encodedKeyIn) {
    try {
        KeyFactory keyfactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        EncodedKeySpec encodedkeyspec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKeyIn);
        return keyfactory.generatePublic(encodedkeyspec);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        //Insert error handling
    }
}
```

The size of the encoded byte array generated by my c++ code is the same as the java example. Yet, the client still throws this error:
`error: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=77, too big.`

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code, edited from @Afshin's post, generates a `RSA` key pair and populates a `std::vector<unsigned char>` with the public key's `PEM` data base64 decoded. The data in the vector is equivalent to the data in the `byte[]` generated by the java function `getEncodedPubKey()` posted in the quesiton. The openssl function that solved my problem was `PEM_read_bio()` its documentation is here [PEM_read_bio](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/PEM_read_bio.html). This function decodes the key data in the `PEM` formatted `BIO`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

struct BioDeleter {
      void operator()(BIO* bio) { BIO_free(bio); }
};

struct KeyCtxDeleter {
      void operator()(EVP_PKEY_CTX* ctx) { EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx); }
};

using BIO_ptr = std::unique_ptr<BIO, BioDeleter>;
using PKEY_CTX_ptr = std::unique_ptr<EVP_PKEY_CTX, KeyCtxDeleter>;

int main() {
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = nullptr;

    PKEY_CTX_ptr ctx(EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, nullptr));

    EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx.get());

    EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(ctx.get(), 1024);

    EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx.get(), &pkey);

    BIO_ptr bio(BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()));
    PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY(bio.get(), pkey);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);

    long size = 0;
    char* dummy1 = NULL;
    char* dummy2 = NULL;
    unsigned char* data = NULL;
    PEM_read_bio(bio.get(), &dummy1, &dummy2, &data, &size);
    OPENSSL_free(dummy1);
    OPENSSL_free(dummy2);

    std::vector<unsigned char> decodedKey(data, data+size);
    OPENSSL_free(data);
}
```

Note: There is no error handling as this is just an example

Answer (score 1):

This small code generates a `RSA` key-pair and stores public key into a string with `PEM` format. Check if it solves your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

struct BioDeleter {
      void operator()(BIO* bio) { BIO_free(bio); }
};

struct KeyCtxDeleter {
      void operator()(EVP_PKEY_CTX* ctx) { EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx); }
};

using BIO_ptr = std::unique_ptr<BIO, BioDeleter>;
using PKEY_CTX_ptr = std::unique_ptr<EVP_PKEY_CTX, KeyCtxDeleter>;

int main() {
  EVP_PKEY *pkey = nullptr;

  PKEY_CTX_ptr ctx(EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, nullptr));
  if (!ctx)
    return -1;

  if (EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx.get()) <= 0)
    return -1;

  if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(ctx.get(), 2048) <= 0)
    return -1;

  if (EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx.get(), &pkey) <= 0)
    return -1;

  BIO_ptr bio(BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()));
  auto res = PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY(bio.get(), pkey);
  EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);

  if (res <= 0)
    return -1;

  BUF_MEM* mem = nullptr;
  BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio.get(), &mem);
  auto str = std::string{mem->data, mem->data + mem->length};
  std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

In addition, you can read `PEM` is java side like this:

```
public static RSAPublicKey readPublicKey(File file) throws Exception {
    String key = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), Charset.defaultCharset());

    String publicKeyPEM = key
      .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
      .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "")
      .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");

    byte[] encoded = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKeyPEM);

    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
    return (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
}
```

This code comes from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-read-pem-file-keys).

Comment: Sadly this did not solve my problem, although I believe it is close. This produces a string with a header, the base64 encoded key, and a footer. I'm pretty sure that what I need is the base64 encoded key decoded as a `char*`.

Comment: Update: I did a little bit of testing and the comment above is exactly what I need, the base64 encoded key decoded into a buffer.

Comment: @Guac I updated answer to show how you can read from `PEM` in java side. You can use that or bring similar changes to C++ side.

Comment: Sorry for being difficult, but is there another way that doesn't involve altering the client side (I'm trying to maintain backwards compatibility between the new server and older clients). I could always just parse the `PEM` formatted string and decode the key, but I was wondering if there was a better way using Openssl. Thanks again

Comment: @Guac in that case you need `DER` encoded (which you get with i2d_ methods)